# xrandr --scale does not work on DisplayLink outputs

Tags: graphics, xrandr, displaylink

Can anyone confirm/deny that `xrandr --scale` has no effect on DisplayLink outputs?

Comment: Not working for me either.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Feature request here: http://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/16077313-fix-linux-driver-scaling However I recently discovered that you can daisy chain DisplayPorts meaning that I now don't need my DisplayLink any more.

Comment: I have a monitor attached via DisplayPort, and there `xrandr --scale` does work. Was that your question?

Comment: @Supernormal No, DisplayPort != DisplayLink.